# W3 Total Cache + S3 + Cloudfront.

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, cdn

For a small site, what WordPress/site files normally go into the S3 bucket in order to get optimal use as a CDN?

Comment: I know people have mixed results between the two but I've found Cloudflare's CDN to be far less problematic than local caching plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what WordPress/site files normally go into the S3 bucket in order to get optimal use as a CDN?

Normally the defaults should suffice i.e.,

You'd want to check these options under the "General" section:

- Host attachments
- Host wp-includes/ files
- Host theme files
- Host minified CSS and JS files
- Host custom files

And under "Advanced" section:

- Modify "Theme file types to upload" to something like this:

  ```
  *.css;*.js;*.gif;*.png;*.jpg;*.ico;*.ttf;*.otf,*.woff,*.eot,*.svg
  ```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Move static assets (js and css),media , theme files etc. All the options W3tc gives you.
Best regards.